# how we use operators of implementation class with pointers

Tags: c++, design-patterns, operators, implementation

Vec_MD class is implemented with VecMD_Impl.That can't implement operators from implementation class with using pimple pointer

Implemented class is:

```
class VecMD{
private:
      VecMD_Impl *pimple;
public: 
     ///other elements..//
     ///operators//
     double& operator [] (int index){  //works
           return pimple -> operator[](index);
     }
     VecMD& operator +=(const VecMD& Vec){  //errors
           return pimple -> operator += (Vec);
     }};
```

Implementation class is

```
class VecMD_Impl{
private:
     double *p_;
     int dim;
public:
     ////other elements....////
     //opearators//
     double& operator[](int index){
          return p_[index];
     }
     VecMD_Impl& operator +=(const VecMD_Impl& Vec){
          for(int i = 0 ; i <= Vec.dim; ++i){
               p_[i] += Vec.p_[i];
          }
          return *this;
     }};
```

Is it true -> use operators on implementation class?

If is it true how we use them on pimpl idiom?

Comment: There's a pattern: `operator <symbol>`. `<symbol> operator` does not match that pattern.

Comment: The compiler tells you exactly what's wrong with your code. Have you tried to read the error message?

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'VecMD_Impl::operator+=(const VecMD&)' @Code::Blocks

Comment: I know what the error says, thank you. *You* need to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue fixed with

```
VecMD& operator += (const VecMD& Vec)
{
     pimple -> operator +=(*Vec.pimple);
     return *this;
}
```

Implementation class is same.